# Rearranging and solving an equation in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following velocity equation and I want to solve for `position`. I want Python to define a new equation so that `position = (Velocity + 100) / 0.1`.

However, if I change the velocity equation then I would also have to change the position equation. This is time consuming and I just want Python to solve for position automatically.

```
position = np.arange(-10000, 10001) # An array of integers from -10,000 to 10,000
Velocity = -100 + 0.1 * position # Equation
position = (Velocity + 100) / 0.1
```

Comment: These aren't equations as far as Python is concerned—you're evaluating an expression to a value, and assigning that value to a variable. I think you need to go over a basic tutorial for Python. And, once you've done that, you may want to look at [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/), a library that lets you define equations in Python and treat them like equations, the way you want to (so, e.g., you can take an equation that relates velocity to position and tell it to solve for position, instead of having to write a new equation).

Comment: I thought about using sympy but I wasn't sure if I could plug in numerical values for the symbols

Comment: @NEMM2020 Why don't you read sympy documentation to see if they allow you to do that?

Comment: You _can_ assign numeric values to the symbols, but normally what you do is _substitute_ numeric values. In other words, you don't say "x is now 20", you say, "Solve that equation for x=20". Like doing math on paper, instead of like normal Python (or most other programming languages).

Comment: But you still really do need to understand the basics of assignment in Python before you start writing sympy equations (and assigning them to Python variables) or you'll just get even more confused. I think the Sage tutorial is probably a good place to start—it goes through assignment, equality, etc. in Python very early on, but in a way designed to make sense to mathematicians rather than programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging equations needs symbolic math. You need SymPy for that.

For example, define the symbols (usually these are single characters, not words):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sympy
>>> v, p = sympy.symbols('v p')
```

Now you can make an expression for `v`:

```
>>> vexpr = -100 + p / 10
```

And you can define an equation to solve:

```
>>> veq = sympy.Eq(v, vexpr)
>>> sympy.pprint(veq)
    p       
v = ── - 100
    10      
>>> pexpr, = sympy.solve(veq, p)
>>> pexpr
10*v + 1000
```

And you can turn your expression into a Python function, which will work on your `position` array:

```
>>> f = sympy.lambdify(p, vexpr)
>>> position = np.arange(-10000, 10001)
>>> f(position)
array([-1100. , -1099.9, -1099.8, ...,   899.8,   899.9,   900. ])
```

You can change your expression for `v` and re-solve or re-compute these other things.